# Android: get contact id after insert

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I need to store the contact id value after create a new contact, in order to be able to reference it in other moment. For example, I create a new contact, and after that I want to delete it from its contact id, so I need to retrieve the contact id value after create a new contact. This is how I create new contacts:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, tipoCuenta).withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, cuenta).build());

//Insert some data here....

c.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

//Here, I want to retrieve contact id
```

How can I do that?

Comment: can u more elaborate it..what problem you are getting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [ContentResolver.applyBatch()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#applyBatch%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E%29) method returns an array of [ContentProviderResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderResult.html) objects, one for each operation. Each of these has the uri of the inserted contact (in the format `content://com.android.contacts/raw_contacts/<contact_id>`).

So to get the contact's id you just have to parse this uri, i.e.

```
ContentProviderResult[] results = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
int contactId = Integer.parseInt(results[0].uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Comment: I would suggest using ContentUris.parseId(contentProviderResult.uri); to get the id of the resource from the ContentProvider.

Comment: To people who are unaware. This solution returns RAW_CONTACT_ID, not the CONTACT_ID.

Answer (score 8):

Improving on matiash answer:

The [ContentResolver.applyBatch()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#applyBatch%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E%29) method returns an array of [ContentProviderResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderResult.html) objects, one for each operation. If your first operation adds RawContact then first element of result array will contain uri to added RawContact (in the format content://com.android.contacts/raw_contacts/[raw_contact_id]).

If you are interested in raw_contact_id then following is enough:

```
    final ContentProviderResult[] results = contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(results[0].uri);
```

But raw_contact_id on some devices might be different than contact_id - In order to get contact_id you have to do following:

```
    final ContentProviderResult[] results = contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    final String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID };
    final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(results[0].uri, projection, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToNext();
    long contactId = cursor.getLong(0);
    cursor.close();
```

Comment: This answer saved my day! Thank you so much!

I always got a different id from the creation result, when using the other answers. But the id actually was something else. Exactly what this solution produced. Thanks again <3

Comment: This is the real answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

here a code snipped i used

```
    newContactUri = null;
    try {
        ContentProviderResult[] res = globalContext.getContentResolver()
                .applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        if (res != null && res[0] != null) {
            newContactUri = res[0].uri;
            /**
             * als Ergebnis erhaelt man eine URI, mit der man die raw
             * contact-id auslesen kann.
             */
            if (debug) {
                Log.d(TAG, "URI added contact:" + res[0].uri.toString()
                        + " l: " + res.length);
            }

            subQuery(newContactUri); // setzt contactRawID

        } else if (debug)
            Log.e( ....);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (debug)
            Log.d( .... );
    }
```

and this is the subroutine subQuery

```
/**
 * <pre>
 * nachdem ein user angelegt ist, wird damit 
 * die contactRawID gesetzt 
 * 
 * @param contactUri
 *            ... Ergebnis aus ContentProviderResult
 * @return void
 * </pre>
 */
public void subQuery(Uri contactUri) {
    if (debug)
        Log.i(TAG, "subQuery() ");

    contactRawID = -2;
    // Content Resolver
    String contactIdString = null;
    String displayName = null;
    ContentResolver contentResolver = globalContext.getContentResolver();
    String[] mainQueryProjection = { ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY };

    Cursor subQueryCursor = contentResolver.query(contactUri,
            mainQueryProjection, null, null, null);
    if (subQueryCursor != null) {
        if (debug)
            Log.d(TAG, "subQueryCursor != null ");
        while (subQueryCursor.moveToNext()) {
            contactIdString = subQueryCursor.getString(0);
            displayName = subQueryCursor.getString(1);
        }
        ;
        try {
            subQueryCursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (debug)
                Log.d(TAG, .... );
        }
        contactRawID = Integer.parseInt(contactIdString);
    }
    return;
}
```

many sorry for german comment text 
but i hope this helps a little bit