# Get ContactId at the time of inserting a new contact programmatically to phone in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contacts

I am trying to get **contactId** of newly added contact programmatically. Contact is being added successfully and fetches the **contactID** from *ContentProviderResult[]* but **contactId** which I am getting is not the correct one. I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23530185/6583944) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24746012/6583944) answer but **contactId** is not the correct one. Here is my code

```
 ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> contentProviderOperation = new ArrayList<>();
      ......
      ......

ContentProviderResult[] results = getActivity().getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, contentProviderOperation);
long contactId = ContentUris.parseId(results[0].uri);
```

I have also tried the below code:

```
ContentProviderResult[] results = getActivity().getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, contentProviderOperation);
            Uri myContactUri = results[0].uri;

            int lastSlash = myContactUri.toString().lastIndexOf("/");
            int length = myContactUri.toString().length();
            int contactID = Integer.parseInt((String) myContactUri.toString().subSequence(lastSlash+1, length));
```

But the **contactId** I am getting here is not the correct one. Please Correct me if I am going something wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working regularly I have find a way to find out the correct **contactId** by the following code:

```
public static int getContactIDFromNumber(String contactNumber, Context context) {
        contactNumber = Uri.encode(contactNumber);
        int phoneContactID = new Random().nextInt();
        Cursor contactLookupCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, contactNumber), new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
        while (contactLookupCursor.moveToNext()) {
            phoneContactID = contactLookupCursor.getInt(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
        }
        contactLookupCursor.close();

        return phoneContactID;
    }
```

Pass the **contactId** of newly added contact that is present in an arrayList.
I know this is not the correct way to find the contact. But it works for me.